# Why does loading saved R file increase CPU usage?

Tags: r, file-io, cpu-usage

I have an R script that I want to run frequently. Few months ago when I wrote it and initiated, there was no problem.
Now, my script is consuming almost all (99%) of the CPU and its slower than it used to be. I am running the script in a server and other users experience slow response from the server when the script is running.
I tried to find out the piece of code where its slow. The following loop is taking almost all the time and CPU that is used by the script.

```
for (i in 1:100){
    load (paste (saved_file, i, ".RData", sep=""))
    Do something (which is fast)
    assign (paste ("var", i, sep=""), vector)
}
```

The loaded data is about 11 MB in each iteration. When I run above script for an arbitrary "i", the loading of file step takes longer time than other commands.
I spent few hours reading forum posts but could not get any hint about my problem. It would be great if you could point out if there's something I am missing or suggest more effective way to load a file in R.

EDIT: Added space in the codes to make it easier to read.

Comment: "taking longer" does not mean "using more CPU."  What tools are you using to check CPU and memory usage?  For example, if Windows, <CTRL>-<ALT>-<DEL> ; <ALT>-T to bring up the TaskMgr will let you observe these.  `Rprof` can tell you which command is taking up elapsed time.

Comment: I am using "top" command in linux to see the CPU usage. I also checked %CPU just by loading the file in every iteration. %CPU increases on doing so. Now, it seems to me that the object remains in the memory although I over-write it in every iteration (but i am not sure). Note: All the saved files I load in each iteration have same variable name.

Comment: Have you tried examining what is in the saved files separately?  It sounds just like there is probably more in there than you realize.

Comment: I checked and tried to remove data that I dont need, but the size of the file does not decrease significantly.

Comment: I'd imagine that the only CPU hogs in load is the decompression and then allocation of memory.  Did you confirm what is being stored in your save file?  Save file size hasn't changed over time?  Maybe your file grew (although it sounds like you may have done this in response to Dason's comment).  The other possiblity is that there is some other problem on the server... how much RAM is free when you start your script?  How much is free during the run. Perhaps it is hitting the swap file hard?

Comment: Thanks @rpierce I got everything fixed from someone else long time ago. However, I dont remember the details anymore. Thanks everyone anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste(saved_file, i, ".RData", sep = "")
```

Loads a object at each iteration, with name `xxx1`, `xxx2`, and so on. 
Did you tried to `rm` the object at the end of loop? I guess the object stays in memory, regardless of your variable being reused.

> Just a tip: add spaces in your code (like i did), it's much more easier to read/debug.

Comment: Yes it is creating a variable in each iteration but they are much smaller than the loaded file. Did you mean that multiple variables might be the issue? I even tried to store the vectors as columns of a matrix but doesn't help. BTW, do you mean spaces between words/characters or between lines?